# angularjs breaking http long pooling post request

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm doing http post long pooling request. I want to cancel that request when stopping the service.
My code looks like this:

```
app.service("ContactsService", function($http, $rootScope, $timeout, $q, ContactsFactory) {
  var requestCanceler = $q.defer();

  this.startHttpRequest = function(userId) {
      var httpRequest = $http.post($rootScope.base_url + '/contacts/req', { toId: userId }, timeout: requestCanceler.promise});

 httpRequest.success(function(data){
      console.log("success");
    });
    httpRequest.error(function(data, status){
      console.log("error");
    });
      }

  this.stopService = function(){
    console.log("stop contacts service");
    requestCanceler.resolve("request canceled");
  } 

}
```

when I'm stopping the service my application is hanging, it's because I do requestCanceler.resolve; When I change it to .reject its not hanging but the http post request is still pending.

How I can break the post request?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an error handler to the http promise.

Comment: sorry I have success and error callbacks, like edited, but I have no console log when resolving propmise...

Comment: Try chaining the handlers and the promise

Comment: Please elaborate on "my application is hanging"! Resolving the timeout promise is the correct way to cancel a `$http` call.

Comment: hanging mean it hangs :) I'm testing my app in ripple in chrome so I have to kill that tab. It just hangs...

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour--can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

The AngularJS documentation states that the promise has to be **resolved** for AngularJS to cancel the request:

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

This can also be seen in the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9f4f5937112655a9881d3281da8e72035bc8b180), the error/reject callback is not set:

```
timeout.then(timeoutRequest);
```

The request cancelling on a rejected promise is not supported.

Comment: Thanks guys, adding then with success and error calbacks worked :)